# Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function hour(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I get the error PG::Error: ERROR: function hour(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
I am trying to convert MySQL to PostgreSQL database.

My Query:

```
SELECT volt as volt1, max(current) as current1, max(total_load) as total_load, HOUR(created_at) as hourly from "rms_dc_power_history" where "rms_id" = 2 and "created_at"::date = 2022-09-03 and "created_at"::time > 00:00 and "created_at"::time <= 24:00 group by HOUR(created_at)
```

Comment: try this : SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at);

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html)  did you find that function?